# How do you append to a file in Perl 6?

Tags: io, raku

I was trying this and a few other things but it truncates the file each time:

```
my $file = 'primes.txt';
sub MAIN ( Int:D $low, Int:D $high where * >= $low ) {
    unless my $fh = open $file, :w, :append {
        die "Could not open '$file': {$fh.exception}";
    }

    for $low .. $high {
        $fh.put: $_ if .is-prime;
    }
}
```

Changing this to `open $file, :a` also seems to truncate the file.
This is 2018.04 on macOS.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::Handle): `:w      same as specifying   :mode<wo>, :create, :truncate`. So behavior exactly up to spec. When you specify `:w`, `:append` is dropped in favor of `:truncate`. Use `:a` instead of `:w :append`

Comment: I see the same problem with `:a` though.

Comment: If Perl 6 is going to ignore something you pass, it should warn you about it.

Comment: sorry, but I don't see the problem (using 2018.04). `perl6 append-file.p6 1 20 `, the file contains: `2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19`
Then `perl6 append-file.p6 200 300`and it appends `19
211
223
227
229
233
239
241
251
257
263
269
271
277
281
283
293
`(I include the 19 here) With respect to ignoring something, well, that's a different piece of cloth altogether. Maybe raising an exception or a warning causes more confusion.

Comment: plain old `open $file, :a` should not truncate, and does not on the Perl6 version I built last month (though I'm on Windows, not MacOS).

Answer (score 8):

Perl6 `&open` semantics are based on [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/open.html), with the following mapping:

```
:mode<ro>  --> O_RDONLY
:mode<wo>  --> O_WRONLY
:mode<rw>  --> O_RDWR
:create    --> O_CREAT
:append    --> O_APPEND
:truncate  --> O_TRUNC
:exclusive --> O_EXCL
```

For convenience, the following shortcuts are provided:

```
:r      --> :mode<ro>
:w      --> :mode<wo>, :create, :truncate
:x      --> :mode<wo>, :create, :exclusive
:a      --> :mode<wo>, :create, :append
:update --> :mode<rw>
:rw     --> :mode<rw>, :create
:rx     --> :mode<rw>, :create, :exclusive
:ra     --> :mode<rw>, :create, :append
```

Not all platforms supported by Rakudo (eg Windows, JVM, not even POSIX itself) support all possible combinations of modes and flags, so only the combinations above are guaranteed to behave as expected (or are at least supposed to behave that way).

Long story short, a simple `:a` absolutely should do what you want it to do, and it does so on my Windows box. If it really truncates on MacOS, I'd consider that a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Using `:mode<wo>, :append` works although this wouldn't be the first thing most people are going to reach for when they see `:a`:

```
my $file = 'primes.txt';
sub MAIN ( Int:D $low, Int:D $high where * >= $low ) {
    unless my $fh = open $file, :mode<wo>, :append {
        die "Could not open '$file': {$fh.exception}";
        }

    for $low .. $high {
        $fh.put: $_ if .is-prime;
        }

    $fh.close;
    }
```

The problem is that Perl 6 tends to silently ignore named parameters. It also looks like [roast/open.t](https://github.com/perl6/roast/blob/0d7781fd4619aa9eb5d040b689b448e02ff5fa26/S32-io/open.t) doesn't actually test this stuff through the user interface. It plays various tricks that should probably be unrefactored.

Comment: FYI: While the combination `:mode<wo>, :append` makes sense to me given the doc definitions of `:mode<wo>` and `:append`, I noticed that [the doc for the `open` routine](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/open) says it calls the [`open` method on an `IO::Handle`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::Handle#method_open) and the doc for the latter says that "Support for combinations of modes other than what is listed above ... might work or might cause the Universe to implode". The combination `:mode<wo>, :append` is not listed above that sentence. So it might work today but not tomorrow.

Comment: @raiph That link is in reference to methods, but isn't `open` here a subroutine? Don't subroutines care about extra named arguments (unlike methods)?

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms: `&open` is implemented as `multi sub open(IO() $path, |c) { IO::Handle.new(:$path).open(|c) }`, passing th arguments through to th method...

Comment: @briandfoy: `:a` is supposed to be equivalent to `:mode<wo>, :create, :append` and should work as expected. In contrast, `:mode<wo>, :append` lacks the `:create` and should die if the file doesn't already exist

Comment: Disagreement is not the same thing as misunderstanding.

Comment: @raiph: the P6 open modes are based on POSIX semantics; the problem is that those are almost, but not quite fully supported on Windows and the JVM

Comment: Hi brian. Presuming your last comment is a response to mine... Indeed. I think that distinction is critically important. It remains unclear to me if *you* disagree with or misunderstand or don't care about the interface consistency principle (a Larry / Perl 6 design thing) or Rakudo's current lack of warning about non-use of named arguments (a tuit / implementation deficit thing) or that it's important to distinguish between them. Interface consistency is often inappropriately maligned. Your comment about "the problem" seems to blame the principle, not Rakudo, or not care about the difference.

Comment: brian writes "Using `:mode<wo>, :append` works". This warrants a warning. First, the doc explicitly says that argument combinations that are not explicitly listed are explicitly unsupported. Second, per Christoph, "a simple `:a` absolutely should do what you want it to do, and it does so on my Windows". Imo you should not use the solution shown in this answer.

Comment: brian writes "The problem is that Perl 6 tends to silently ignore named parameters." The issue covered by this SO is specific to the `open` function which wisely allows devs to use whatever combination of modes they choose but only *supports* certain combinations. The doc lists those combinations and explicitly states that other combinations, such as the one brian is using, "might work or might cause the Universe to implode, depending on a particular implementation". P6's interface consistency principle, which brian deems a problem, is technically entirely unrelated to this `open` issue.